# Account Creation "/createpost/" Service Unavailable on production, works on local

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, apache, create

I am currently having an issue with my server where creating a customer account gives this error, the account is created but it still shows this error instead of a confirmation page/redirect to account page.

My local version works perfectly. I replaced all the files from production from local and this issue still exists. The only difference I can think of is that in my production environment there may be different configuration settings. Can a configuration setting cause this?

Has anyone came across this before? Or know a possible solution? I was hoping it was just something in the configuration settings but I have been unable to find anything. The database and readable/writeable as well.

I just cannot understand why it creates the account, fails to redirect(?) and then shows a service unavailable error but my local version is okay.

Edit: To be more exact the process that fails is the login and redirect. So once you go back to say the home page you are still not logged in although you can log in afterwards.

Fix Found: So Log errors gave me nothing but I noticed when I tested an email for a sale it gave me an error.  There was a unused module that conflicted with the email process and because this caused a failure it would lock the account create procedure at the email confirmation process. Removing + Uninstalling the offending module fixed the issue immediately.

Comment: Nothing in your `var/log` and `var/report` folders?

Comment: Sadly both are empty since being cleared yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the error the only thing that comes to mind is that your production server may be missing something in the php config or have a different php version.  Compare the php version on your local vs your production site by running phpinfo() in a php file.

Next you can try running Magento's magento-check.php. Download it from here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/_media/magento-check.zip then unzip it in your web root.  Run it on your production server to ensure that you aren't missing anything and that your server has the minimum requirements.

Comment: I found the answer, it was a email conflict causing it to fail.But that link may be very helpful in the future so thank you. I did not know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running Magento's magento-check.php, this is due to

> You are missing the mcrypt extension.